# How to get a MultipleSelect ListBox with GWT using UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm working on an app developped with GWT using UiBinder.
In one view, I have a ListBox that needs to allow multiselection.

The app is currently using the method setMultipleSelect(boolean isMultipleSelect) to enable multi-selection on the ListBox.
That method is now deprecated and it is advised to use the constructor ListBox(boolean isMultipleSelect).

The problem is that I'm not constructing that ListBox, is it done when binding (I think, I'm not really sure how it's all working).

My code is like that :

```
interface ViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, View> {}

private static ViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ViewUiBinder.class);

private Widget widget;
@UiField
ListBox listBox;

@Inject
public View() {
  widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
  listBox.setMultipleSelected(true);
}
```

Does anyone know how to init the ListBox with the multiselection constructor constructor and make it work ?

Thanks,

Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `provided = true` annotation paramenter for `UiField` and initialize the field. If you don't want to initialize the listbox with the field, but in the `View` constructor, set the statement before `uiBinder.createAndBinUi(this);`

```
@UiField(provided = true)
ListBox listBox = new ListBox(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this. I'll let you know if it's working.

Comment: i didn't look enough in the project, it was already used in another presenter.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any of the bean-like properties of UI widgets using the de-capitalized property names inside your UiBinder template. It looks like this:

```
<g:ListBox ui:field="listBox" multipleSelect="true" />
```

I tend to avoid the `provided=true` annotation parameter until it's absolutely necessary, and it isn't in this case.

Comment: But doing that is the same as calling the method setMultipleSelected which is deprecated, isn't it ?

Comment: @clavelm: Yes that is the same as calling the method setMultipleSelected and since you wanted to avoid it, I didn't suggest this solution ;-)

Comment: Reading comprehension fail, sorry. But if you still have to code for IE6 considerations, my sincerest condolences.